# How to check if text has 6 numbers

Tags: php

I have a jobs site , and my visitors are able to add jobs on the front end of it , i need to check the job details to see if it has a phone number within it or not using php code

example of the 6 digit numbers could be 123456 , 533434 and no other format,
if there is any 6 digit numbers an error message would show up to make visitors remove it from the details section

I need something like this :

```
if (strpos($_POST[details],'######') !== false)
{
    echo 'remove the phone number from job details';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[1-9]\d{5}/',$_POST[details])) {
    echo 'remove the phone number from job details';
}
```

Comment: Your regex could be shortened to just `[1-9]\d{5}`.

Comment: No problem, @rakesh. You can edit your answer if you want to, but it's a minor change anyway. I misread the original question, so I've now deleted my answer. +1 to yours since you were the first to correctly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a regular expression like this: `\d{6}`

```
if (preg_match('@\d{6}@', trim($_POST['details']))) {
    // Then the phone number is valid                                       
}
```